# How to access variables from a Class Decorator from within the method it's applied on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

*NOTE

I've compiled an answer based on everything written by @AlexHall and @juanpa.arrivillaga. See below.*

---

I'm writing a **Class Decorator** to be applied on methods. This practice is quite uncommon, but luckily the StackOverflow community helped to get it done:
[Class decorator for methods from other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402709/class-decorator-for-methods-from-other-class/63402870)

Now I want to take things one step further. The method being invoked should have access to some variables from the **Class Decorator**. Here is a small self-contained example of what I've tried:

```py
import functools

class MyDecoratorClass:
    def __init__(self, method) -> None:
        functools.update_wrapper(self, method)
        self.method = method
        self.decorator_var = None
        return

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype) -> object:
        return type(self)(self.method.__get__(obj, objtype))

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> object:
        self.decorator_var = "hello world"
        retval = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
        return retval

class Foobar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @MyDecoratorClass
    def foo(self):
        # I want to access the 'decorator_var' right here:
        value = self.foo.decorator_var
        print(f"foo decorator_var = {value}")
```

Let's test:

```sh
>>> f = Foobar()
>>> f.foo()
foo decorator_var = None
```

As you can see, the variable `decorator_var` is not accessed correctly. I believe this happens right at the moment I'm trying to access the variable:
`value = self.foo.decorator_var`

Accessing `self.foo` invokes the `__get__()` method from `MyDecoratorClass`. This returns a new `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance which has its `decorator_var` initialized to `None`.

Is there a way I can access `decorator_var` from within the `foo()` method?

Comment: I mean, I'm not sure how else to explain it. The first method *explicitly creates a new instance*,  `return type(self)(...)` the other approach doesn't, `return types.MethodType(...)`

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is based on everything @AlexHall and @juanpa.arrivillaga wrote here:
[Class decorator for methods from other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402709/class-decorator-for-methods-from-other-class/63402870). I want to thank them for their help.*

---

Let `foo()` be a method from class `Foobar`, and let `foo()` be decorated with a `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance. So the question is:

> Can the code running in `foo()` access variables from the `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance?

For this to work properly, we need to think first about how many `MyDecoratorClass()` instances get created over the course of the program. After lots of research and help from @AlexHall and @juanpa.arrivillaga, I concluded that there are basically three options. Let's first glance over them rapidly and then investigate them profoundly one-by-one.

### Overview

> **OPTION 1**
> One `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance spawns at the very beginning of your program for the (unbound) `foo()` method, and it's the only instance used to invoke `foo()`. Each time you invoke `foo()`, this `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance inserts the corresponding `Foobar()` instance in the method through a trick.

This approach allows for communication between the code running in `foo()` and the `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance. However, if you've got several `Foobar()`-instances `f1` and `f2` in your program, then `f1.foo()` can have an impact on the way `f2.foo()` behaves - because they share the same `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance!

> **OPTION 2**
> Again one `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance spawns at the very beginning of the program for the (unbound) `foo()` method. However, each time you access it, it returns a NEW `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance on the fly. This instance is short-lived. It dies immediately after completing the method.

This approach doesn't allow for any communication between the code running in `foo()` and the `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance. Imagine you're *inside* the `foo()` code and you try to access a variable from the `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance:

```py
@MyDecoratorClass
def foo(self):
    # I want to access the 'decorator_var' right here:
    value = self.foo.decorator_var
    print(f"foo decorator_var = {value}")
```

The moment you even try to reach `decorator_var`, you essentially get a new `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance returned from the `__get__()` method!

> **OPTION 3**
> Just like before, one `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance spawns at the very beginning of the program for the (unbound) `foo()` method. Each time you access it (which implies calling its `__get__()` method), it checks *who* is trying to access. If it's an unknown `Foobar()`-object, the `__get__()` method returns a NEW `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance with a bound `foo()`-method. If it's a known `Foobar()`-object, the `__get__()` method retrieves the `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance it has spawn before for that very `Foobar()`-object, and returns it.

This option ensures a one-to-one relationship: each `Foobar()`-object gets exactly one `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance to wrap its `foo()` method. And each `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance belongs to exactly one `Foobar()`-object<sup>(*)</sup>. Very neat!

<sub>(*) The `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance spawn at the very beginning of the program for the unbound `foo()` method is the only exception here. But this instance gets only used for its `__get__()` method, which serves as a `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance-factory: spawning, returning and storing exactly one `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance per `Foobar()` instance upon which `foo()` has been invoked.</sub>

Let's go through each of the options. Before doing so, I'd like to stress that the *only implementation difference* between the three options is in the `__get__()` method!

---

### 1. FIRST OPTION: Stick to one instance

Let `MyDecoratorClass` be a decorator for method `foo` defined in class `Foobar`:

```py
import functools, types

class MyDecoratorClass:
    def __init__(self, method) -> None:
        functools.update_wrapper(self, method)
        self.method = method

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype) -> object:
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.__call__(obj, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> object:
        return self.method(*args, **kwargs)

class Foobar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @MyDecoratorClass
    def foo(self):
        print(f"foo!")
```

Even if you never instantiate `Foobar()`, the Python interpreter will still create ONE instance of `MyDecoratorClass` in the very beginning of your program. This one instance is created for the UNBOUND method `foo()`. OPTION 1 basically implies to stick to this `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance for the rest of the program. To achieve this, we need to make sure that the `__get__()` method doesn't re-instantiate `MyDecoratorClass()`. Instead, it should make the existing `MyDecoratorClass()` APPEAR to hold a bound method:

```
    ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
    │ def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):                                  │
    │     return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.__call__(obj, *args, **kwargs) │
    └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

As you can see, `self.method` NEVER gets bound to a `Foobar()`-instance. Instead, it just appears that way. Let's do a test to prove this. Instantiate `Foobar()` and invoke the `foo()` method:

```sh
>>> f = Foobar()
>>> f.foo()
```

The method invocation essentially exists of two parts:

> PART 1
> `f.foo` invokes the `__get__()` method. This gets invoked on the ONE AND ONLY `MyDecoratorClass()` instance, which holds an unbound method in `self.method`. It then returns a lambda-reference to its `__call__()` method, but with the `Foobar()` instance added to the *args tuple.

> PART 2
> The parenthesis `'()'` after `f.foo` are applied on WHATEVER `__get__()` returned. In this case, we know that `__get__()` returned the `__call__()` method from the ONE AND ONLY `MyDecoratorClass()` instance (actually a bit modified with lambda), so naturally that method gets invoked.
>
> Inside the `__call__()` method, we invoke the stored method (the original foo) like so:
>
> ```py
> self.method(*args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> While `self.method` is an unbound version of `foo()`, the `Foobar()` instance is right there in the first element of *args!

In short: Each time you invoke the `foo()` method on a `Foobar()`-instance, you deal with the ONE AND ONLY `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance which holds an unbound `foo()` method-reference and makes it appear to be bound to the very `Foobar()`-instance you invoked `foo()` on!

**Some extra tests**
You can verify that `self.method` is always unbound in the `__call__()` method with:

- `hasattr(self.method, '__self__')`
- `self.method.__self__ is not None`

which always prints `False`!

You can also put a print-statement in the `__init__()` method to verify that `MyDecoratorClass()` gets instantiated only once, even if you invoke `foo()` on multiple `Foobar()` objects.

**Notes**
As @AlexHall pointed out, this:

```py
return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.__call__(obj, *args, **kwargs)
```

is essentially the same as:

```py
return lambda *args, **kwargs: self(obj, *args, **kwargs)
```

That's because applying parenthesis `'()'` on an object is essentially the same as invoking its `__call__()` method. You can also replace the return statement with:

```py
return functools.partial(self, obj)
```

or even:

```py
return types.MethodType(self, obj)
```

---

### 2. SECOND OPTION: Create a new instance per invocation

In this second option, we instantiate a new `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance upon each and every `foo()` invocation:

```
    ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
    │ def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):                       │
    │     return type(self)(self.method.__get__(obj, objtype))    │
    └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

This `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance is very short-lived. I've checked with a print-statement in the `__del__()` method that it gets garbage collected right after foo() ends!

So this is what happens if you invoke `foo()` on several `Foobar()` instances:

```sh
>>> f1 = Foobar()
>>> f2 = Foobar()
>>> f1.foo()
>>> f2.foo()
```

As always, a `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance for the unbound `foo()` method gets spawn before any `Foobar()`-object gets born. It remains alive until the end of the program. Let's call this one the *immortal `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance*.

The moment you invoke `foo()`, you create a new short-lived `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance. Remember, the `foo()` invocation essentially happens in two steps:

> STEP 1
> `f1.foo` invokes the `__get__()` method on the immortal `MyDecoratorClass()`-
> instance (there is no other at this point!). Unlike OPTION 1, we now spawn a NEW `MyDecoratorClass()` and pass it a bound `foo()` method as argument. This new `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance gets returned.

> STEP 2
> The parenthesis `'()'` after `f1.foo` are applied on WHATEVER `__get__()` returned.
> We know it's a NEW `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance, so the parenthesis `'()'` invoke its `__call__()` method. Inside the `__call__()` method, we still got this:
>
> ```py
> self.method(*args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> This time however, there is NO `Foobar()`-object hidden in the args tuple, but the stored method is bound now - so there is no need for that!

`f1.foo()` completes and the short-lived `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance gets garbage collected (you can test this with a print-statement in the `__del__()` method).

It's time for `f2.foo()` now. As the short-lived `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance died, it invokes the `__get__()` method on the immortal one (what else?). In the process, a NEW instance gets created and the cycle repeats.

In short: Each `foo()` invocation starts with calling the `__get__()` method on the immortal `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance. This object always returns a NEW but short-lived `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance with a bound `foo()`-method. It dies after completing the job.

---

### 3. THIRD OPTION: One `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance per `Foobar()`-instance

The third and last option combines the best of both worlds. It creates one `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance per `Foobar()`-instance.

Keep an `__obj_dict__` dictionary as a class-variable and implement the `__get__()` method like so:

```
    ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
    │ def __get__(self, obj, objtype):                              │
    │     if obj in MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__:                  │
    │         # Return existing MyDecoratorClass() instance for     │
    │         # the given object, and make sure it holds a bound    │
    │         # method.                                             │
    │         m = MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj]                │
    │         assert m.method.__self__ is obj                       │
    │         return m                                              │
    │     # Create a new MyDecoratorClass() instance WITH a bound   │
    │     # method, and store it in the dictionary.                 │
    │     m = type(self)(self.method.__get__(obj, objtype))         │
    │     MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj] = m                    │
    │     return m                                                  │
    └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

So whenever `foo()` gets invoked, the `__get__()` method<sup>(*)*</sup> checks if a `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance was already spawn (with bound method) for the given `Foobar()`-object. If yes, that `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance gets returned. Otherwise, a new one gets spawn and stored in the class dictionary `MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__`<sup>()</sup>.

<sub>(*) Note: This `MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__` is a class-level dictionary you have to create yourself in the class definition.</sub>

<sub>(*) Note: Also here, the `__get__()` method always gets invoked on the immortal `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance that is spawn at the very beginning of the program - before any `Foobar()`-objects were born. However, what's important is what the `__get__()` method *returns*.</sub>

**WARNING**
Keeping an `__obj_dict__` to store all the `Foobar()`-instances has a downside. None of them will ever die. Depending on the situation, this can be a huge memory leak. So think about a proper solution before applying OPTION 3.

I also believe this approach doesn't allow recursion. To be tested.

---

### 4. Data exchange between the code in `foo()` and the `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance

Let's go back to the initial question:

> Let `foo()` be a method from class `Foobar`, and let `foo()` be decorated with a `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance. Can the code running in `foo()` access variables from the `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance?

If you implement the **first** or the **third option**, you can access any `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance variable from within the `foo()` code:

```py
@MyDecoratorClass
def foo(self):
    value = self.foo.decorator_var
    print(f"foo decorator_var = {value}")
```

With `self.foo` actually accessing the `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance. After all, `MyDecoratorClass()` is a wrapper for `self.foo`!

Now if you implement **option 1**, you need to keep in mind that `decorator_var` is shared amongst all `Foobar()`-objects. For **option 3**, each `Foobar()`-object has its own `MyDecoratorClass()` for the `foo()` method.

---

### 5. One step further: apply `@MyDecoratorClass` on several methods

**Option 3** worked fine - until I applied `@MyDecoratorClass` on two methods:

```py
class Foobar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @MyDecoratorClass
    def foo(self):
        print(f"foo!")

    @MyDecoratorClass
    def bar(self):
        print("bar!")
```

Now try this:

```sh
>>> f = Foobar()
>>> f.foo()
>>> f.bar()
foo!
foo!
```

Once a `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance exists for the `Foobar()` object, you'll always access this existing one to invoke the method. In our case, this `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance got bound to the `foo()` method, so `bar()` never executes!

The solution is to revise the way we store the `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance in `__obj_dict__`. Don't just spawn and store one `MyDecoratorClass()`-instance per `Foobar()`-object, but one instance per (`Foobar()`, `method`) combination! That requires an extra parameter for our decorator, eg:

```py
@MyDecoratorClass("foo")
def foo(self):
    print(f"foo!")

@MyDecoratorClass("bar")
def bar(self):
    print("bar!")
```

A decorator with a parameter essentially means double-wrapping the underlying method/function! So let's design a wrapper for that:

```py
def my_wrapper(name="unknown"):
    def _my_wrapper_(method):
        return MyDecoratorClass(method, name)
    return _my_wrapper_
```

and now use this wrapper:

```py
class Foobar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @my_wrapper("foo")
    def foo(self):
        print(f"foo!")

    @my_wrapper("bar")
    def bar(self):
        print("bar!")
```

Finally, we need to refactor the `MyDecoratorClass`:

```py
import functools, types

class MyDecoratorClass:
    __obj_dict__ = {}
    def __init__(self, method, name="unknown") -> None:
        functools.update_wrapper(self, method)
        self.method = method
        self.method_name = name
        return

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype) -> object:
        if obj in MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__.keys():
            # Return existing MyDecoratorClass() instance for
            # the given object-method_name combination, and make
            # sure it holds a bound method.
            if self.method_name in MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj].keys():
                m = MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj][self.method_name]
                return m
            else:
                # Create a new MyDecoratorClass() instance WITH a bound
                # method, and store it in the dictionary.
                m = type(self)(self.method.__get__(obj, objtype), self.method_name)
                MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj][self.method_name] = m
                return m

        # Create a new MyDecoratorClass() instance WITH a bound
        # method, and store it in the dictionary.
        m = type(self)(self.method.__get__(obj, objtype), self.method_name)
        MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj] = {}
        MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj][self.method_name] = m
        return m

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> object:
        return self.method(*args, **kwargs)


    def __del__(self):
        print(f"{id(self)} garbage collected!")
```

Let's revise: at the beginning of the program, before any `Foobar()`-object is born, the Python interpreter already spawns two `MyDecoratorClass()`-instances: one for the unbound `foo()` and another for the unbound `bar()` method. These are our immortal `MyDecoratorClass()`-instances whose `__get__()` methods serve as `MyDecoratorClass()` factories.

Nothing new here. This happened also before we did these changes. However, now we store the `method_name` at the moment the factories are built! This way, the factory method `__get__()` can make use of that information to spawn and store not just one `MyDecoratorClass()`-instances per `Foobar()` object, but one for the (`Foobar()`, `"foo"`) and (`Foobar()`, `"bar"`) combination!

This is the complete self-contained program:

```py
import functools, types

class MyDecoratorClass:
    __obj_dict__ = {}
    def __init__(self, method, name="unknown") -> None:
        functools.update_wrapper(self, method)
        self.method = method
        self.method_name = name
        return

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype) -> object:
        if obj in MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__.keys():
            # Return existing MyDecoratorClass() instance for
            # the given object-method_name combination, and make
            # sure it holds a bound method.
            if self.method_name in MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj].keys():
                m = MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj][self.method_name]
                return m
            else:
                # Create a new MyDecoratorClass() instance WITH a bound
                # method, and store it in the dictionary.
                m = type(self)(self.method.__get__(obj, objtype), self.method_name)
                MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj][self.method_name] = m
                return m

        # Create a new MyDecoratorClass() instance WITH a bound
        # method, and store it in the dictionary.
        m = type(self)(self.method.__get__(obj, objtype), self.method_name)
        MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj] = {}
        MyDecoratorClass.__obj_dict__[obj][self.method_name] = m
        return m

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> object:
        return self.method(*args, **kwargs)


    def __del__(self):
        print(f"{id(self)} garbage collected!")


def my_wrapper(name="unknown"):
    def _my_wrapper_(method):
        return MyDecoratorClass(method, name)
    return _my_wrapper_

class Foobar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @my_wrapper("foo")
    def foo(self):
        print(f"foo!")

    @my_wrapper("bar")
    def bar(self):
        print("bar!")
```